# Ruby On Rails - Controller doesn't open page while been called

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, web, ruby-on-rails-7

calculate.html.erb of "calc" controller:

```
<h2>
<%= @count%>
</h2>
```

Form, which do the get request:

```
            <%= form_with url: "/calc", method: :get do |form|%>
                <%= form.label :count, "Введите количество чисел" %>
                <%= form.number_field :count %>
                <%= form.submit "Начать"%>
            <% end %>
```

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # Define your application routes per the DSL in https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  # Defines the root path route ("/")
  # root "articles#index"
  root 'pages#index'
  get '/calc', to: 'calc#calculate'
end
```

In terminal, when I submit the form, I see this:

```
Started GET "/calc?count=5&commit=%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C" for ::1 at 2023-01-23 16:51:04 +0300
Processing by CalcController#calculate as HTML
  Parameters: {"count"=>"5", "commit"=>"Начать"}
  Rendering text template
  Rendered text template (Duration: 0.0ms | Allocations: 4)
Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 0.5ms | Allocations: 206)
```

calc_controller.rb:

```
 def calculate
    render plain: params[:count].inspect
    @count = params[:count]
  end
```

P.s The URL doesn't change when I submit form

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
render plain: params[:count].inspect
```

in your controller causes Rails to not render your view file but a plain text response.

Just remove that line and Rails should automatically render the view found in `app/views/calc/calculate.html.erb`